# How can I format my drive completely to prepare it for any OS, not specifically Ubuntu?

Tags: hard-drive

I am sad to say it, but I am turning my back on Ubuntu. One last thing I need to know though is how to nuke my hard drive. I have tried a couple sites, but they are all using Ubuntu Live CD's, which I am assuming means they want to get rid of a standing OS, white downloading Ubuntu. What I need is the opposite. I just need to clear my hard drive, and have it ready for another OS, but I would rather not say what kind.

Thanks to all of you in advance, and Ubuntu will always have a special place in my CD rack ^-^

Comment: Question really has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: You do not need to "nuke" it to install a new O/S as Rinzwind stated. But if you really want to "nuke" it maybe try DBAN :http://www.dban.org/.

Comment: I disagree that this question is off-topic. The uninstallation of Ubuntu is definitely on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the installation media you use for the OS you put on that system.
All installation media will have a 'delete partition' option.

It is the easiest method since you will need to format the disc anyways if you go back to Windows or MacOS. Just remove the partitions and create 1 or more new ones.

Comment: This is the easiest method, but not the most secure method. If security is important to you, look at [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/4678/securely-erasing-all-data-from-a-hard-drive).

Comment: @flimm he wants to reuse the disc not sell it. So security (ie. recovering the old OS) is not an issue (well at least the question does not suggest it is)

Comment: I agree. It's just that some people wrongly assume a plain format is secure, so I wanted to mention it, for the lurkers.